# Show that, for any constants a ∈ (0, 1) and b ∈ R, the equation x = a sin x + b has a unique solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I received the first part by using what was stated below and using the Mean Value Thm. And now I have to show that there is a unique solution, I was thinking using the Intermediate Value Thm to prove this??? how do i incorporate it?

Comment: Please edit you post to include what you tried, and any other helpful context, "and explain thoroughly."  The best way to "really understand" this problem is to participate and contribute towards the solution. No one expects you to go solo....but many of do expect you explain what you don't understand, and to participate (responding to comments, making edits as needed, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the equation has two distinct solutions $x,y$ given $a\in(0,1)$. Then, $$|x-y| = a|\sin x - \sin y| = a|\cos\varepsilon||x-y|$$, for some $\varepsilon$ between $x,y$ by the Mean Value Theorem. But this is a contradiction because $a|\cos\varepsilon|<1$.

This proves that if the equation has a solution, then it is unique. For the existence, note that $f(x)= x-a\sin x$ is an odd function and $\lim_{x\to\infty} = \infty$, so $f(x) = b$ must have a solution for every real $b$.

Comment: How come you went from aIsinx - sinyI = aIcosEIIx-yI>

Answer (score 0):

Just **intuitively** speaking.
For $a$ positive but less than $1$, $y= a \sin{x}$ contact $y=x$ only at $x=0$ and then remains below $y=x$.
When you raise or lower $y= a \sin{x}$ by a constant $b$, then the steepness (derivative) of the line $y=x$ will always be greater than that of $y= a \sin{x}$.
The graph of the sine is confined in a strip of width less than $2$ and is continuous. The line will always cross the sine: but soon after the cross point, because of the lesser derivative, the sine will not succeed and "catch" the line again.